# Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNSVGSvgView, js engine: hermes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

> Error: Tried to register two views with the same name RNSVGSvgView, js engine: hermes

I have react-native project and I want to use @lnanhkhoa/react-native-iconly but additionally downloading react-native-svg is required. After downloading I got the error Tried to register two views with the same name RNSVGSvgView, js engine: hermes.

```
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { useColorScheme } from "react-native";
import { Paragraph,  TamaguiProvider, Theme, YStack,Text } from "tamagui";
import { Home } from '@lnanhkhoa/react-native-iconly'
import config from "./tamagui.config";
export default function App() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    Urbanist : require('./assets/fonts/Urbanist-Black.otf')
  });
  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <TamaguiProvider config={config}>
      <Theme name={colorScheme === "dark" ? "dark" : "light"}>  
        <YStack
          f={1}
          jc="center"
          ai="center"
          backgroundColor={"$backgroundSoft"}
        >
          <Paragraph color="$color" jc="center">
            {colorScheme}
          </Paragraph>
          <Text>Ol artık</Text>
          <Home set="bold"/>
          
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </YStack>
      </Theme>
    </TamaguiProvider>
  );
}
```

```
{
  "name": "eventla-front",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@lnanhkhoa/react-native-iconly": "^2.2.4",
    "@tamagui/animations-react-native": "^1.43.13",
    "@tamagui/babel-plugin": "^1.43.13",
    "@tamagui/config": "^1.43.13",
    "@tamagui/font-inter": "^1.43.13",
    "@tamagui/theme-base": "^1.43.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables": "^0.4.4",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-web": "^0.19.7",
    "tamagui": "^1.43.13",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.14",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I removed package.json.lock and restored it,

I uninstalled iconly and reinstalled,

I used react-native-svg @13.4.0 it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

Package to download:

```
npx expo install react-native-svg
```

It was fixed when I downloaded and tried again.